Quadratic Inequalities solutions
There are no solutions to $x^2+x+3\leq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
So why does the solution of $x^2+x+3>0$ mean $x$ can be any $x\in \mathbb{R}$?
Can someone please help me by solving the given inequalities?

We have $x^2+x+3=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{11}{4}\geq\frac{11}{4}>0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. (as any real number squared is greater than/ equal to zero).
So the second inequality is always true for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. It is also the fact that if $x^2+x+3>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then certainly there will be no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+x+3\leq 0$.
